# CSS selector that ends with something and not contains something

Tags: jquery, selector

I need to find any `<a>` tags, which its href ends with `'pdf'` and **not** contains `'test'`.

like this;

```
<a href="/abc/tes.pdf">link</a>
```

All I know is the first condition;

```
jQuery('a[href$=".pdf"]')
```

Teach me the rest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery('a[href!="test"][href$=".pdf"]');
```

Or better:

```
jQuery('a[href$=".pdf"]').not('[href="test"]');
```

And here's the reason:

> Because [name!="value"] is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using [name!="value"] cannot take advantage of
>   the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   $("your-pure-css-selector").not('[name="value"]') instead.

**EDIT:** The "better" may not be correct here, [value$="name"] isn't CSS2 pure selector either, but jQuery documentation doesn't mention that. Some additional research is required here...

**EDIT 2:** It looks like I didn't thought this through. What you probably want is:

```
jQuery('a[href$=".pdf"]').not('a[href*="test"]');
```

Which reads: select all `a` elements which have `href` attribute that ends with ".pdf" but do **not** select `a` elements which have "test" as a substring anywhere in `href` attribute.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: +1 for answering, explaining and reading the question properly (which I, apparently, didn't...). And correcting my answer would've turned it into yours, which would have been somewhat redundant.

Comment: @David, which doesn't make my answer right. See the edit. PS. You wrote that you're pretty good with js and css in your profile, maybe you could help me? :) Thanks for +1 anyway.